# how to get from $x<x^2 + y^2$ to $\left(\frac12\right)^2<\left(x-\frac12\right)^2 +y^2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> How to get from $x<x^2 + y^2$ to $\left(\frac12\right)^2<\left(x-\frac12\right)^2 +y^2$?

This is were I saw it:
 [Sketch all points in the complex plane such that $\mathrm{Re}(1/z)<1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210390/sketch-all-points-in-the-complex-plane-such-that-mathrmre1-z1)

Answer (score 4):

Add on both sides $1/4$:

$${1\over 4}<{1\over 4} -x+x^2+y^2$$
so 
$$ \big({1\over 2}\big)^2<(x-{1\over 2})^2+y^2$$